# What is the best way of handling return in CakePhp Models?

Tags: cakephp, error-handling

I'm researching for coding standards for my cakephp 2.8 project. I'm looking for a good way of handling return values in my models.

For example in my model I want to return a data which I queried from database. I want to say, "hey I found the data you want and here it is" or "sorry I couldn't find anything" or "I encountered an error while looking for the data you want"

So there could be 3 types of return,

1. Data is found without any error
2. No data found without any error
3. An error has occured while looking for data

Any help will be appriciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you need that?
Everything is already built in

A) $data contains data

B) empty array (no data found obviously)

C) exception being thrown, you can either catch or not.

So the problem doesnt exist in the first place IMO :)

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest you to maintain an array and return that in json format using json_encode function. 
Array can be as follow:

```
$arr['error'] = 1;
$arr['data'] = $data;
```

and then you can send the data as:

return json_encode($arr);

and while reciveing data  you can decode it

json_decode($arr);